# Regex match just first result or second from HTML table

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm using regex in-app script javascript. I try to get just the first value or the second value from each table but not work.

```
   <table>
      <td class="bar">
        <td class="center">hello1</td>
        <td class="center">hello2</td>
        <td class="center">hello3</td>
     </td>
   </table>

   <table>
     <td class="bar">
       <td class="center">hello1</td>
       <td class="center">hello2</td>
       <td class="center">hello3</td>
     </td>
   </table>
```

my code regex: `/(?<=<td class=\"center\">).*?(?=<\/td>)/gi`

this code selects all values Hello. I want just select Hello1 from the first table td and second table td.
I remove global but give me just the first td from the first table.

the hello value is dynamic not fixed.

[image]

Comment: There aren't any `<tr>` tags in your example HTML. Can you also be more specific about which values you want to return? E.g. name them all "hello1", "hello2", etc and say "I expect 'hello1' and 'hello4' to be returned"

Comment: sorry bro I mean `<td` tag

Comment: I edited value the values is dynamic scraping from HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a regular expression something [like this](https://regexr.com/6j9q9) which retrieves the text you expect...

[image: regular expression run results]

Essentially matching the tags by excluding `<>` characters within the tag.

However I think an easier and less error prone way to do this in JavaScript and DOM is to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead, for example...

```js
let c = document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-of-type(2)');

console.log(Array.from(c).map(i => i.innerText));
```

```html
   <table>
      <td class="bar">
        <td class="center">hello1</td>
        <td class="center">hello2</td>
        <td class="center">hello3</td>
     </td>
   </table>

   <table>
     <td class="bar">
       <td class="center">hello1</td>
       <td class="center">hello2</td>
       <td class="center">hello3</td>
     </td>
   </table>
```

Comment: thanks, brother, but if I want to select just hello2 from each table

Comment: With querySelectorAll you just change it to `td:nth-of-type(3)` instead to retrieve the "hello2" nodes. It's more difficult with the regular expression and as I said, I would recommend using querySelectorAll.

Comment: can you see that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818492/regex-app-script-get-value-href-from-html-scraping